# Trouble finding locator for search button on etsy.com

Tags: java, selenium

needing help finding a locator for the search button on etsy.com. Trying to search for lace on site but when I run the code, the search button doesn't click.

here is an image of the button:
[image: here is an image of the button]

The xpath chropath has given me is super long.

This is my code:

```
WebElement Lace = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='global-enhancements-search-query']"));
Lace.sendKeys("Lace");

Thread.sleep(5000);


WebElement Search= driver.findElement(By.xpath( "//body[@class='transitional-wide is-signed-in no-touch is-responsive en-US USD US is-global-nav wt-focus-visible']/div[@id='gnav-header']/header[@id='gnav-header-inner']/div[@class='wt-display-flex-xs wt-pr-lg-3 wt-flex-lg-1 wt-flex-basis-xs-full wt-order-xs-2 wt-order-lg-0']/div[@class='global-enhancements-search-browse-wrapper wt-display-inline-block wt-flex-xs-1']/form[@id='gnav-search']/div[@class='wt-menu wt-menu--full-width wt-menu--offset-below-trigger']/div[@class='wt-input-btn-group global-enhancements-search-input-btn-group wt-menu__trigger']/button[@class='wt-input-btn-group__btn']/span[@class='etsy-icon wt-nudge-b-1']/*[1]"));
Search.click(); //button click
```

Answer (score 0):

Shorter:

cssSelector: `button[type='submit'][value='Search']`

xpath: `//button[@type='submit' and @value='Search']`

If this doesn't work, try using a JavaScriptExecutor to click on the element, or move to it before clicking.